# Angular JS default url having no hash

Tags: angularjs, routes

At the moment I have html5 mode turned for url's in my angular site.

But I was just wondering is there anyway I could have my default url load without the "#!/" i.e. domain/#!/, I know I will have it back when I switch to a route but would be nice to not have it in default url homepage.

Here is my current routeprovider

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
  'use strict';
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl: '/views/search.html',
      controller : 'SearchCtrl'
    })
    .when('/result',{
      templateUrl: '/views/result.html',
      controller : 'resultCtrl'
    })
    .when('/options',{
      templateUrl: '/views/options.html',
      controller : 'optionsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

Comment: I doubt there's anything you could do that wouldn't be considered a hack. The prefix is something handled internally to `ngRoute`. Is it really that much of a problem? Your home url will still work with or without it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hashbang mode is a fallback for html5, so either

- use html5
- hack angularjs
- put homepage out of angular application
- rewrite/forward urls on web server

Read more on [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

Answer (score 0):

**if you are not using server side language then put this code in html head.**

```
<base href="/">
```

like :

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

and put this in config block:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

**if you are using server side language then use this code:**

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

insteed of

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

and and put this code in config block:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```